# I have question about C++ memory address difference type calculate memory address offset ？

Tags: c++

```
    int i=20; 
    const char* d = "adsadasdadas"; //not use
    const char* k = "use";
    int delta = (char*)&k - (char*) & i;

    cout << &i << endl;
    cout << &k << endl;
    cout << delta << endl;
    cout << &i + delta << endl;
```

```
output:
000000B51D10F984
000000B51D10F9C8
68
000000B51D10FA94
```

&i + delta !=&k ,  how to fix?  68 will use as hexdecimal,and 68 change to decimal 104,+&i =000000B51D10FA94 in this case

Comment: the difference between two pointers is not in bytes, its in units of the thing pointed to, you lied to the compiler about the types when you calculated delta so you got the wrong answer

Comment: BTW, the compiler is allowed to store variables in *registers*.  In most processors, registers do not have addresses; they are a mechanism internal to the processor.  However, using the `operator&` forces the compiler to store the variable somewhere in memory because it needs an address.  There is no guarantee where in memory the variable will be located, except it will be in memory that has Read & Write access.  Also, there is no guarantee that the variables will be consecutive in memory.  Again, remember that variables can be placed into processor registers.

Comment: @pm100 No, the delta is correct (it is calculated in bytes), but applying that delta to `&i` afterwards is wrong, since the delta is in bytes while `&i` is not a pointer to a byte, but is a pointer to an `int`. Pointer arithmetic is performed in units of the pointed type, not in bytes. So `&i + delta` overshoots. But `(char*)&i + delta` would work.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - thats exactly what I said, but not as clearly

Comment: @pm100 the way you worded it sounds backwards than it really is

Answer (score 2):

Subtracting non-null pointers which do not point to (or one-past) the same object or into (or one-past) the same array causes undefined behavior.

Similarly, adding integers to pointers is only allowed as long as you stay within the bounds of an array (or one-past it).

`&k` is a pointer to the variable `k` and `&i` is a pointer to the variable `i`. These are completely independent variables, not part of a shared array or in any other way connected.

Therefore your program has undefined behavior. It is impossible to retrieve the difference between addresses of unrelated variables in this way and even if you used a legal approach, the result would be completely unspecified and cannot be used to retrieve a pointer to the other variable via pointer arithmetic.

---

As a further, more obvious issue, you are substracting the pointers in type `char`, but adding the result to a `int` pointer. Pointer arithmetic measures in terms of the number of elements of the corresponding array, not in bytes. The size of a `char` is `1` byte and so `delta` will be in units of bytes (if it wasn't UB to begin with). But pointer arithmetic in `&i + delta` expects `delta` to measure in number of `int`s, meaning `delta` should be scaled by `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: So is it not possible to calculate different types of addresses in this way at all?

Comment: @魏达强 You can cast the pointers to `std::uintptr_t` and then take the difference. But the result will be pretty much useless. What would you ever need this for?

Comment: I want to read EBP register store value and add address offset，then get the new address value string

Comment: @魏达强 Use inline assembly for doing stuff like that. The C++ language doesn't know about registers and doesn't allow you to access them. Inline assembly are compiler extensions allowing to do stuff like this directly embedded in C++ code (how possible this is in the specific case or how it would be useful, I don't know). I still doubt that you _actually_ need this.

Comment: I have been able to get the address from the EBP register from asm, but when calculating the offset, just like this program, I can't get the address correctly, the problem lies in the offset calculation

Comment: @魏达强 your offset calculation is fine (if you ignore the UB), you are just not applying the offset correctly afterward. Since the offset was calculated in bytes, you can only apply it as-is to a byte pointer, not an int pointer.  So, just like you casted `&i` to a byte pointer to calculate the offset, you need to cast `&i` to a byte pointer again when applying the offset (and then cast the resulting address to your desired pointer type)